# How do I solve $\int\sin^5 x$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

Should I transform $\int\sin^5 x$ into  $\int (\sin^2 x)^2 \sin x \; \Bbb d x$ to solve it? Or should I use a different trigonometric identity?

Comment: Almost there: note that $\sin^2x = 1 - \cos^2 x$, then make a $u$-substitution with $u = \cos x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, you can make the change of variable $u=\cos(x)$ and use $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$. Then, you just have a polynomial to integrate.

Comment: I'm having problems with trigonometric identities. This site www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html says that $\sin^2 (x) = \frac{1}{2} (1 - \cos(2x))$.

Comment: Yes, this is true. But it is also true that $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$. Here, this identity is more useful.

Comment: Yeah the one mentioned on the site is good for even powers of single trig functions

Answer (score 5):

$$\sin^5 x = \left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^5 = \frac{1}{32i}\left(e^{5ix}-5e^{3ix}+10 e^{ix}-10 e^{-ix}+5e^{-3ix}-e^{-5ix}\right)$$
gives:
$$ \sin^5 x = \frac{1}{16}\left(\sin(5x)-5\sin(3x)+10\sin(x)\right)$$
that is way easier to integrate.

Comment: I need to use trigonometric identities to solve my homework but thank you

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira: isn't the Fourier sine series of $\sin^5 x$ a trigonometric identity?!

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ is a simple trigonometric identity that follows immediately from Euler's formula.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sir, even I had thought of evaluating the integral in this way. However, Sir, what would we do if the power to which$\sin(x)$ becomes very large (say for instance 20)? How would we expand $\dfrac{e^{\iota z}-e^{-\iota z}}{2}$?

Comment: @BetterWorld For larger powers it's better to do IBP and then use a recursive formula

Comment: @Dylan Thanks Sir. Unfortunately I don't know recursive formulae:(

Comment: Something like this 
$$ \begin{align*} \int \sin^n x\,dx &= \int \sin x\, \sin^{n-1}x\,dx \\ &= -\cos x\,\sin^{n-1}x + (n-1)\int \cos^2 x\,\sin^{n-2}x\, dx \\ &= -\cos x\,\sin^{n-1}x + (n-1)\int(1-\sin^2 x)\sin^{n-2}x\,dx\end{align*} $$ 
$$ \Rightarrow n\int\sin^n x\,dx = -\cos x\,\sin^{n-1}x  + (n-1)\int\sin^{n-2}x\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \sin^5x dx = \int \sin x(\sin^2x)^2 dx = \int \sin x(1-\cos^2x)^2 dx $$

Letting $u = \cos x \implies du  = -\sin(x)dx$ we get

$$\int  (1-\cos^2x)^2 \sin x dx  = -\int (1-u^2)^2 du  = \int -1+2u^2 -u^4 du  = -u + \dfrac{2}{3} u^3 - \dfrac{u^5}{5} + C = - \cos x + \dfrac{2}{3} \cos ^3 x - \dfrac{\cos^5x}{5} + C$$

Comment: $du=-\sin x dx$

Comment: D'oh, you're right. Correcting

Answer (score 1):

$$\int (\sin^2 x)^2\sin x dx=\int (1-\cos^2 x)^2\sin x dx=\int (1-2\cos^2 x+\cos^4 x)\sin x dx$$
$$=-\cos x+\frac{2}{3}\cos^3 x-\frac{1}{5}\cos^5 x+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Another answer from a totally different point of view.

[***I found***](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%20sin%5Bx%5D%5Eq) that:

$$ \int \sin^q{x} \, \mathrm{d} x = -\cos (x) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-q}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos ^2(x)\right),$$ 
which leads to $-\frac{1}{15} \cos (x) \left(3 \cos ^4(x)-10 \cos ^2(x)+15\right)$ for $q = 5$.

Cheers!