# how to solve this trigonometric reduction question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, reduction-formula

> The question asks to put $\sin^5 \theta$ in the form
> $$
> A\sin 5\theta + B\sin 3\theta + C\sin \theta. 
> $$

I have tried changing the $\sin$ into a $\sin^4$ and then putting it in terms of cos, and then using the reducing formula.

But I end up with a very long equation, as it is only a 4 mark question on the paper I am doing I assume I have made a mistake along the way. Does anyone have any alternate ideas as how best to solve it?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332315/evaluate-sin5-x-using-imaginary-part-of-e-iota-x or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330661/how-do-i-solve-int-sin5-x

Comment: @Gerry Myerson The second reference doesn't refer to the same issue.

Comment: @Jean, did you read the answer posted there by Jack?     https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1330716

Comment: My bad. Indeed, I have seen the question, not the (last) answer.

Answer (score 7):

One way to solve the problem is to assume there exist constants $A$, $B$ and $C$ where

$$\sin^5\theta = A\sin 5\theta + B\sin 3\theta + C\sin \theta \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

is true for all angles $\theta$. Then let $\theta$ be several convenient values to get linear equations which can be solved for $A$, $B$ and $C$. First, with $\theta = 90^{\circ}$ we get

$$1 = A - B + C \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Next, $\theta = 45^{\circ}$ gives

$$\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} = -\frac{A}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{B}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{C}{\sqrt{2}} \;\;\to\;\; 1 = -4A + 4B + 4C \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Multiplying \eqref{eq2A} by $4$ and adding \eqref{eq3A} results in

$$5 = 8C \;\;\to\;\; C = \frac{5}{8} = \frac{10}{16} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Using this value of $C$, and $\theta = 30^{\circ}$, in \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$\frac{1}{32} = \frac{A}{2} + B + \frac{5}{16} \;\;\to\;\; 1 = 16A + 32B + 10 \;\;\to\;\; -9 = 16A + 32B \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

With \eqref{eq4A} in \eqref{eq2A}, we get

$$1 = A - B + \frac{10}{16} \;\;\to\;\; 16 = 16A - 16B + 10 \;\;\to\;\; 6 = 16A - 16B \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Next, \eqref{eq5A} minus \eqref{eq6A} gives

$$-15 = 48B \;\;\to\;\; B = -\frac{5}{16} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

This in \eqref{eq6A} shows that

$$6 = 16A + 5 \;\;\to\;\; A = \frac{1}{16} \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Finally, substituting \eqref{eq4A}, \eqref{eq7A} and \eqref{eq8A} into \eqref{eq1A} gets what your image shows as being the answer, i.e.,

$$\sin^5\theta = \frac{1}{16}(\sin 5\theta - 5\sin 3\theta + 10\sin\theta) \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

---

Another way is to use the angle sum formulas to express $\sin 5\theta$ and $\sin 3\theta$ as polynomials in $\sin\theta$, then ensure all of the exponents are $0$ except for the fifth power term. First, we have

$$\sin 5\theta = \sin(3\theta + 2\theta) = \sin 3\theta\cos 2\theta + \cos 3\theta\sin 2\theta \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

Next, we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sin 3\theta & = \sin(2\theta + \theta) \\
& = \sin 2\theta\cos\theta + \cos 2\theta\sin\theta \\
& = (2\sin\theta\cos\theta)\cos\theta + (1 - 2\sin^2\theta)\sin\theta \\
& = 2\sin\theta(1 - \sin^2\theta) + \sin\theta - 2\sin^3\theta \\
& = 3\sin\theta - 4\sin^3\theta
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$

and

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\cos 3\theta & = \cos(2\theta + \theta) \\
& = \cos 2\theta\cos\theta - \sin 2\theta\sin\theta \\
& = (1 - 2\sin^2\theta)\cos\theta - (2\sin\theta\cos\theta)\sin\theta \\
& = \cos\theta(1 - 4\sin^2\theta)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{12}\label{eq12A}$$

Using \eqref{eq11A} and \eqref{eq12A} in \eqref{eq10A}, along with $\cos 2\theta = 1 - 2\sin^2\theta$ and $\sin 2\theta = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$, results in

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sin 5\theta & = (3\sin\theta - 4\sin^3\theta)(1 - 2\sin^2\theta) + \cos\theta(1 - 4\sin^2\theta)(2\sin\theta\cos\theta) \\
& = (3\sin\theta - 10\sin^3\theta + 8\sin^5\theta) + 2\sin\theta(1 - 4\sin^2\theta)(1 - \sin^2\theta) \\
& = (3\sin\theta - 10\sin^3\theta + 8\sin^5\theta) + 2\sin\theta(1 - 5\sin^2\theta + 4\sin^2\theta) \\
& = 5\sin\theta - 20\sin^3\theta + 16\sin^5\theta
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{13}\label{eq13A}$$

Using \eqref{eq11A} and \eqref{eq13A} in \eqref{eq1A}, then gathering terms according to powers of $\sin\theta$, we get the following for the coefficients of the $\sin\theta$, $\sin^3\theta$ and $\sin^5\theta$ terms, respectively,

$$5A + 3B + C = 0 \;\;\to\;\; C = -5A - 3B \tag{14}\label{eq14A}$$

$$-20A - 4B = 0 \;\;\to\;\; B = -5A \tag{15}\label{eq15A}$$

$$16A = 1 \;\;\to\;\; A = \frac{1}{16} \tag{16}\label{eq16A}$$

Using \eqref{eq16A} in \eqref{eq15A} gives $B = -\frac{5}{16}$. Using the determined values of $A$ and $B$ in \eqref{eq14A} shows that $C = -5\left(\frac{1}{16}\right) - 3\left(-\frac{5}{16}\right) = \frac{10}{16}$. This matches the results in \eqref{eq8A}, \eqref{eq7A} and \eqref{eq4A}, so we then also get \eqref{eq9A}.

---

Last, but not least, as suggested in the linked questions in [Gerry Myerson's question comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4835710/how-to-solve-this-trigonometric-reduction-question#comment10296564_4835710), and by [Jean Marie's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4835710/how-to-solve-this-trigonometric-reduction-question/4835736?noredirect=1#comment10296631_4835736), an easier and more direct method is to use $\sin \theta = \frac{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$ and [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to get, since the $\cos$ terms cancel, that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sin^5\theta & = \frac{1}{(2i)^{5}}(e^{i(5\theta)} - 5e^{i(3\theta)} + 10e^{i\theta} - 10e^{-i\theta} + 5e^{-i(3\theta)} - e^{-i(5\theta)}) \\
& = \frac{1}{32i}(i(2\sin 5\theta) + 5i(2\sin 3\theta) + 10i(2\sin\theta))) \\
& = \frac{1}{16}(\sin 5\theta + 5\sin 3\theta + 10\sin\theta)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{17}\label{eq17A}$$

I didn't mention this initially since I didn't want to assume you have already studied or know about complex numbers.

Comment: Expanding $\dfrac{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^5}{(2i)^5}$ is a much more direct way.

Comment: @JeanMarie I agree, but I assumed the OP had not yet studied or used complex numbers. Nonetheless, I've added that method as well to my answer, just in case and to make it more complete.